# gcc не видит структуру

Tags: c, gcc, структуры, компилятор, объявление

Есть код,при компиляции с помощью GCC компилятора выдает ошибку,при использовании компилятора Visual C++ все компилируется без проблем(код идентичный),как исправить эту проблему,не хотелось бы менять компилятор и текущую среду разработки(Codeblocks).Новый проект пробовал создавать,не помогает.
[image: Ошибка]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define bool int

static bool n;

struct list {
    int field; // поле данных
    struct list *next; // указатель на следующий элемент
    struct list
        *prev; // указатель на предыдущий элемент
};

struct list *init( int a )  // а- значение первого узла
{
    struct list *lst;
    // выделение памяти под корень списка
    lst = ( struct list * )malloc( sizeof( struct list ) );
    lst->field = a;
    lst->next = NULL; // указатель на следующий узел
    lst->prev = NULL; // указатель на предыдущий узел
    return( lst );
}

struct list *addelem( list *lst, int number )
{
    struct list *temp, *p;
    temp = ( struct list * )malloc( sizeof( list ) );
    p = lst->next; // сохранение указателя на следующий узел
    lst->next =
        temp; // предыдущий узел указывает на создаваемый
    temp->field =
        number; // сохранение поля данных добавляемого узла
    temp->next =
        p; // созданный узел указывает на следующий узел
    temp->prev =
        lst; // созданный узел указывает на предыдущий узел

    if( p != NULL ) {
        p->prev = temp;
    }

    return( temp );
}

struct list *deletelem( list *lst )
{
    struct list *prev, *next;
    prev = lst->prev; // узел, предшествующий lst
    next = lst->next; // узел, следующий за lst

    if( prev != NULL ) {
        prev->next = lst->next;    // переставляем указатель
    }

    if( next != NULL ) {
        next->prev = lst->prev;    // переставляем указатель
    }

    free( lst ); // освобождаем память удаляемого элемента
    return( prev );
}

struct list *deletehead( list *root )
{
    struct list *temp;
    temp = root->next;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    free( root ); // освобождение памяти текущего корня
    return( temp ); // новый корень списка
}

void findelem( list *lst, int goal )
{
    struct list *next;
    next = lst->next;

    if( lst->prev == NULL && lst->field == goal ) {
        n = 1;
        deletehead( lst );
    }
    else if( lst->field == goal ) {
        deletelem( lst );
    }
    else {
        findelem( next, goal );
    }
}

void listprint( list *lst )
{
    struct list *p;
    p = lst;

    do {
        printf( "%d ", p->field ); // вывод значения элемента p
        p = p->next; // переход к следующему узлу
    } while( p != NULL ); // условие окончания обхода
}

void listprintr( list *lst )
{
    struct list *p;
    p = lst;

    while( p->next != NULL ) {
        p = p->next;    // переход к концу списка
    }

    do {
        printf( "%d ", p->field ); // вывод значения элемента p
        p = p->next; // переход к следующему узлу
    } while( p != NULL ); // условие окончания обхода
}

int main()
{
    list *head, *cur;
    int num;
    // Создаем список из 6 элементов
    printf( "a = " );
    scanf( "%d", &num );
    head = init( num );
    cur = head;

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        printf( "a = " );
        scanf( "%d", &num );
        cur = addelem( cur, num );
    }

    listprint( head );
    printf( "\n" );
    cur = head;
    int atr;
    printf( "Vvedit inform atrubyt: " );
    scanf( "%d", &atr );
    struct list *p2 = head->next;
    findelem( cur, atr );

    if( n == 1 ) {
        listprint( p2 );
    }
    else {
        listprint( head );
    }

    printf( "\n" );
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что компилятор MS VS компилирует ваш код как C++ код, в то время как GCC компилирует ваш код как C  код.

Ошибка состоит в том, что перед именем структуры в C вы должны указывать ключевое слово `struct`.

Например, в этом предложении

```
struct list * addelem(list *lst, int number) {
                      ^^^^^
```

компилятор языка C выдаст сообщение об ошибке, так как он не знает, что означает имя `list`.

Напишите в этом предложении и в других, где имеется такая же ошибка, следующим образом

```
struct list * addelem(struct list *lst, int number) {
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Другая возможность исправить ошибку состоит в объявлении typedef_имени для структуры. Например,

```
typedef struct list {
int field; // поле данных
struct list *next; // указатель на следующий элемент
struct list *prev; // указатель на предыдущий элемент
} list;
```

И тогда имя `list` вы можете использовать без ключевого слова `struct`.

Comment: Использовал typedef,компилирует без проблем

Comment: @andybelous2 Как я написал, компилятор MS VS компилировал ваш код как C++ код, поэтому ошибки не возникало.:)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, дело в том, что C++ при объявлении `struct foo ...` создаёт тип `foo`, в то время как C - только `struct foo`. Если вы пишете на C, а не на C++, то либо проставляйте везде `struct list` вместо простого `list`, либо напишите typedef. Если же вы пишете на C++, то используйте компилятор g++ вместо gcc.